# Verilog Parsing Using ANTLR grammar

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, verilog, antlr4

I am trying to create a parser in Java (using Netbeans) which can take in any arbitrary Verilog file as an input and generate a netlist containing gates as the output. The netlist does not have to be optimized.

I have the ANTLR grammar file https://github.com/antlr/grammarsv4/blob/master/verilog/Verilog2001.g4

However, I am not really quite sure how to integrate it into my Java program.

For instance, if I had the following Verilog file as input,

```
module and3(output out, input in1, in2,in3);
  reg r_out;
  assign out = r_out;
  always@(in1, in2, in3)
    begin
      case({in3,in2,in1})
        000: out = 0;
        001: out = 1;
        010: out = 1;
        011: out = 1;
        100: out = 0;
        101: out = 1;
        110: out = 0;
        111: out = 1;
        default: out = 0;
      endcase
    end
endmodule
```

I would like to identify the names of the input and output ports as well as their size. I would also like to identify the always block as well as the case statement block and each assignment within the Case Statement.

So my doubts are:

1) How do I integrate this into my java program

2) How do I use this Verilog Grammar file and read the Verilog code mentioned above to recognize inputs, outputs, case statements, assign statements.

Thanks

Comment: you're trying to write a compiler which synthesises Verilog. The parser is a tiny part of the overall job - even if you wrote your own grammar file, it would only be a few percent of the overall work you're going to have to put in. If you really want to go ahead, your first (small) step is to generate an AST from a Verilog description. Start with a non-Verilog example (C, or something simpler) from the ANTLR website; if you can create and manipulate an AST, that would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently solved a similar task. I started creating an IntelliJ plugin for Verilog using the same grammar file for ANTLR. Currently, it parses Verilog files successfully and does some highlight/completion etc.

Here is my code https://github.com/MrTsepa/jetbrains-verilog-plugin

Firstly I generate ANTLR AST tree with some ANTLR tools (embedded in ANTLR plugin for Idea) and then adapt this tree to IntelliJ's AST format (PSI tree) via [ANTLR adapter](https://github.com/antlr/jetbrains)